# Including twitter+Oauth in iOS 4.0 giving a HTTP error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter-oauth

In my iPhone app (targeting iOS 4.0) I need to integrate Twitter. I have used twitter + OAuth and I am able to successfully post once.

After that it is giving me the following error:

```
F622CF31-9D3F-4FAF-AE0A-50914C1FD0EF failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=403 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 403.
```

Here is my simple Twitter code with delegate methods.

Button click code:

```
if(![_engine isAuthorized]){  
            UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];  

            if (controller){  
                [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
                }  
        } 
        else
        {
               [_engine sendUpdate:@"Hello"];
        }
```

Delegate Methods:

```
- (void)storeCachedTwitterOAuthData:(NSString *)data forUsername:(NSString *)username {  
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  

    [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"authData"];  
    [defaults synchronize];  
}  

- (NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername: (NSString *) username {  
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"authData"];  
}
```

Is there any thing I need to modify to extend OAuth permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer here.

https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/issues/26

This link says that you can not post same tweet twice that what the twitter has denied.
So take care.